# Nacl: File open for *** failed -5

Tags: c++, google-nativeclient

Trying to create a new file on a working filesystem and getting this error:

> ERR|File open for write failed -- Error #: -5

Here is the code:

```cpp
void MyInstance::CreateFile(int32_t /* result */) {
    if (!file_system_ready_) {
        ShowErrorMessage("File system is not open", PP_ERROR_FAILED);
        return;
         }
    pp::FileRef ref(file_system_,"foo.txt");
    pp::FileIO file(this);
    int32_t open_result =
        file.Open(ref,PP_FILEOPENFLAG_WRITE | PP_FILEOPENFLAG_CREATE | PP_FILEOPENFLAG_TRUNCATE, pp::BlockUntilComplete());
    if (open_result != PP_OK) {
      ShowErrorMessage("File open for write failed", open_result); //here is the error
      return;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The -5 error code stand for a [PP_ERROR_BADRESOURCE](https://code.google.com/p/ppapi/source/browse/trunk/c/pp_errors.h?r=237).

It [could be thrown by different objects](https://developer.chrome.com/native-client/pepper_dev/cpp/classpp_1_1_resource), but here, **it's due to the FileRef path**.  [FileRef must contain the fullpath of the file including root](https://developer.chrome.com/native-client/pepper_dev/cpp/classpp_1_1_file_ref#a95aad2e3c8d9b52b1ac09279c8cf8113) not simply the name of the file, like this:

```cpp
pp::FileRef ref(file_system_,"/foo.txt");
```